# PowerShell copy AD objectGUID to ms-ds-consistencyguid

Tags: windows, powershell, azure, active-directory, guid

I am trying to resolve a PowerShell problem that has proved to be more complicated than I first thought. When trying to copy the objectGUID of each domain user into the same users ms-ds-consistencyguid the values do not match. Can anybody help?

I have tried this rough method below but the GUID's do not match:

```
$SGSADUser=get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -eq 'Test10_User'} -Properties objectguid,samaccountname,ms-ds-consistencyguid | Select Samaccountname,Objectguid,ms-ds-consistencyguid

[guid]$SGSADMSDSConsistencyguid = ($SGSADUser.objectguid).ToString()

$SGSADbase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($SGSADMSDSConsistencyguid.ToByteArray())

set-aduser -Identity 'Test10_User' -replace @{'ms-ds-consistencyguid' = $SGSADbase64}
```

[ObjectGUID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAb5F.png)
[ms-ds-ConsistencyGuid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQfhU.png)

Comment: but they match in the screenshots attached?

Comment: Sorry my error I grabbed the screenshot of a manual change the result should be 76 38 55 45 31 51 46 56 6D 6B 75 55 32 76 79 6A 79 69 75 34 56 67 3D 3D

Answer (score 1):

I just ran through this and when you convert to base 64, the value changes.

Try

```
set-aduser -Identity 'Test10_User' -replace @{'ms-ds-consistencyguid' = $SGSADMSDSConsistencyguid}
```

This came out as the correct value when I checked.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Hi Tim thanks for your help, The Hex valuses now match **BF C5 04 D5 01 55 9A 4B 94 DA FC A3 CA 2B B8 56** and 
**BF C5 04 D5 01 55 9A 4B 94 DA FC A3 CA 2B B8 56**
however the displayed values are totally different

Comment: Yeah, this article describes how you can convert the displayed value to the hex value. That's what I used to test. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/39e9cb99-833b-49d3-9058-a6656e6fd7f1/get-msdsconsistencyguid-attribute-via-powershell-ad-module-or-natively-no-quest?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'll give it a go. Regards Graham

Comment: No worries. Good luck Graham.

Comment: How did you go Graham?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond, this worked fine thanks for your help.